# Dotted Quarter to Quarter

Tags: tempo

A piece I'm reading in 3/4 has a BPM of 130 dotted quarters per minute. How would i do a conversion of dotted quarter BPM to quarter? I have no clue on how to convert different note length tempos to the tempo of the beat of a different length note.

Comment: The bpm of 3/4 time doesn't require a dotted anything to designate bpm. It sounds like possibly you're not in 3/4 but a compound time instead. There is no point at all in using 'dotted crotchet as the 'beat' in 3/4 time. making this questin based on false premises. A screenshot of the piece may shed light on the problem - it may be written wrongly.

Answer (score 2):

A dotted quarter note is equivalent to three eighth notes. Since there are 130 dotted quarter notes per minute, that means there are 390 eighth notes per minute. A quarter note is equivalent to two eighth notes. So 390 eighth notes per minute is equivalent to **195 quarter notes per minute**.

Comment: Have you come up with a good reason why the piece should use a dotted ctotchet as the 'beat'?

Comment: @Tim - Considering that I've seen Musescore sheet music in 3/4 time with the *half note* as the "beat", I don't think a good reason is required.

Comment: @Dekkadeci - would that make it 3/8 or 6/8? Neither the same as 3/4.

Comment: @Dekkadeci sorry but I don't think that's a "good reason". And, be aware, this is not something related to things like "evolution of language". The very concept of fractions in music is the relation between beats and subdivisions. If you got a **beat** per minute, it means that there's a *reference beat*, which also becomes the *notation* reference. There are "fringe" situations, obviously, (for instance, if you're coming from a compound rhythm and you want a straight reference to it) but that's not the point: if the piece is in 3/4, giving a dotted quarter reference for timing is just wrong.

Comment: Besides that: published musescore sheet music is *hardly* a reference for standard notation, as we *all* have seen **terrible** notation examples not only on the musescore library, but even in "published" sheet music. There's plenty of terribly written sheet music, the fact that it's published somewhere doesn't make it "right".

Comment: @musicamente - I gave my Musescore example more as an example of poor notation that you just have to roll with than as an example of notation that's any good. Just because the sheet music is poorly notated doesn't mean you don't have to read it.

Comment: for me its easier to multiply by 1.5x directly

Answer (score 2):

To convert dotted quarter to quarter you only need to multiply by 1.5x, as a quarter is 1.5 times faster than a dotted quarter. so 130 BPM in dotted quarters in normal quarter notes would be 130 * 1.5, **which is equal to 195 BPM**, for doing it viceversa you only need to divide by 1.5.